# Form Select / HTML-Select - React Pre-populate / Auto-populate / Autopopulate Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-select, redux-form

I have a working React ReduxForm component. I cannot find an answer in documentation or postings to pre-populate a Select input in the form and also allow the input to be changeable.

Should be an easy thing I am missing.

The problem is only in the Select field, not the change handlers or initial value.

```
<Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
  <select defaultValue={props.initialValues.state} /*onChange={() => updateReducerStateDD(value)}*/>
    <option onSelect={() => updateHandler("Iowa")} value="IA" selected={props.initialValues.state == "IA" ? true : false}>Iowa</option>
    <option onSelect={() => updateHandler("Washington")} value="WA" selected={props.initialValues.state == "WA" ? true : false}>Washington</option>
    <option onSelect={() => updateHandler("Ohio")} value="OH" selected={props.initialValues.state == "OH" ? true : false}>Ohio</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the library React-Bootstrap, the answer is that there is magic going on where the handler is placed in the Select tag and the event.target.value from the option tag that is selected becomes its parameter (automatically).

One caveat is that you must name your value in your database object the same thing that you display in the option tag to the user (for auto-populating).

```
<Form.Group controlId="address.state">
  <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
  {/*for class-based React component use onChange={this.updateHandler}*/}
  {/*herein updateHandler is 'binded' by being an arrow fn in this component*/}
  <Form.Control as="select" onChange={updateHandler}> 
    <option disabled>States</option>
    <option selected={props.initialValues.state == "Iowa" ? true : false}>Iowa</option>
    <option selected={props.initialValues.state == "Washington" ? true : false}>Washington</option>
    <option selected={props.initialValues.state == "Ohio" ? true : false}>Ohio</option>
  </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `const preloadedValue = {selectvalue:'foo'}` with your preloaded value and use a hook

```
const {register,handleSubmit} = useForm({ defaultValue:preloadedValue});
```

and instead of  `<select defaultValue={props.initialValues.state}` use

```
<select ref = {register} name='selectvalue'..
```